# Hadoop hive is not responding

Tags: c#, hadoop, hive

I am using cloudera vm to test hadoop hive.

I am connecting with C# using the Microsoft Hive driver, everything is working good.
Sometimes, after like 30~50 queries, the hive service stops responding and I need to restart it.
Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

To Start Hive Service I used this command:

```
/usr/bin/hive --service hiveserver
```

Update:

On the /tmp/root/hive.log I get a lot of those worrnings:

```
2014-05-01 05:46:50,686 WARN  zookeeper.ClientCnxn (ClientCnxn.java:run(1089)) - Session 0x0 for server localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:21)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:198)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:166)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:245)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doIO(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:68)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:355)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
```

Comment: Cloudera has great logging. dig up the Hive log, which does exist and paste the important error details if any. Also look through the resourcemanager log.

Comment: Hi apesa, I am new with cloudera and hadoop, can you please guide me a bit? each call that I make to the hive, I see that there is a log file, but I haven't saw anything that can lead me to the problems. there is other logs I should check? thanks for the help